# Difference between Iterator and Spliterator in Java8

Tags: parallel-processing, java-8, iterator, spliterator

I came to know while studying that `Parallelism` is a main advantage of `Spliterator`.

This may be a basic question but can anyone explain me the main differences between `Iterator` and `Spliterator` and give some examples?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The names are pretty much self-explanatory, to me. `Spliterator` == *Splittable Iterator* : it can split some source, and it can iterate it too. It roughly has the same functionality as an `Iterator`, but with the extra thing that it can potentially *split* into multiple pieces: this is what `trySplit` is for. Splitting is needed for parallel processing.

An `Iterator` always has an unknown size: you can traverse elements only via `hasNext/next`; a `Spliterator` can provide the size (thus improving other operations too internally); either an exact one via `getExactSizeIfKnown` or a approximate via `estimateSize`.

On the other hand, `tryAdvance` is what `hasNext/next` is from an `Iterator`, but it's a single method, much easier to reason about, IMO. Related to this, is `forEachRemaining` which in the default implementation delegates to `tryAdvance`, but it does not have to always be like this (see `ArrayList` for example).

A Spliterator also is a "smarter" Iterator, via its internal properties like `DISTINCT` or `SORTED`, etc (which you need to provide correctly when implementing your own `Spliterator`). These flags are used internally to disable unnecessary operations; see for example this optimization:

```
 someStream().map(x -> y).count();
```

Because size does not change in the case of the stream, the `map` can be skipped entirely, since all we do is counting.

You can create a Spliterator around an Iterator if you need to, via:

```
Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(yourIterator, properties)
```

Answer (score 53):

An `Iterator` is a simple representation of a series of elements that can be iterated over.

eg:

```
 List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Apple", "Banana", "Orange");
 Iterator<String> i = list.iterator();
 i.next();
 i.forEachRemaining(System.out::println);

#output
Banana
Orange
```

A `Spliterator` can be used to split given element set into multiple sets so that we can perform some kind of operations/calculations on each set in different threads independently, possibly taking advantage of parallelism. It is designed as a parallel analogue of Iterator. Other than collections, the source of elements covered by a Spliterator could be, for example, an array, an IO channel, or a generator function.

There are 2 main methods in the `Spliterator` interface.

**- tryAdvance() and forEachRemaining()**

With tryAdvance(), we can traverse underlying elements one by one (just like Iterator.next()). If a remaining element exists, this method performs the consumer action on it, returning true; else returns false.

For sequential bulk traversal we can use forEachRemaining():

```
 List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Apple", "Banana", "Orange");
 Spliterator<String> s = list.spliterator();
 s.tryAdvance(System.out::println);
 System.out.println(" --- bulk traversal");
 s.forEachRemaining(System.out::println);

 System.out.println(" --- attempting tryAdvance again");
 boolean b = s.tryAdvance(System.out::println);
 System.out.println("Element exists: "+b);
```

Output:

```
Apple
 --- bulk traversal
Banana
Orange
 --- attempting tryAdvance again
Element exists: false
```

**- Spliterator trySplit()**

Splits this spliterator into two and returns the new one:

```
  List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Apple", "Banana", "Orange");

  Spliterator<String> s = list.spliterator();
  Spliterator<String> s1 = s.trySplit();

  s.forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
  System.out.println("-- traversing the other half of the spliterator --- ");
  s1.forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
Banana
Orange
-- traversing the other half of the spliterator ---
Apple
```

An ideal trySplit method should divide its elements exactly in half, allowing balanced parallel computation.

The splitting process is termed as 'partitioning' or 'decomposition' as well.

Comment: how about the size or internal flags? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51459530/1059372