# Spliterator Java 8 - custom implementation

Tags: java, spliterator

I am learning this Java 8 feature and I am really finding it difficult to understand the `Spliterator` interface's `trySplit()` method implementation in case of custom classes for parallel processing of the generated `Stream`.

Can anyone please help me with some good tutorial with a clear example?

Comment: I tried to read this https://www.baeldung.com/java-spliterator tutorrial but ,I found it complicated trySplit() implementation part and also the implementation class of spliterator interface 's logic is not clearly understood to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Iterator and Spliterator in Java8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51453841/difference-between-iterator-and-spliterator-in-java8)

Comment: @manikantgautam -> that does not have explanation with custom class .

Comment: @RamaTripathi it can be annoying when people keep voting to close your question simply because you are asking for a tutorial which is unfortunately not considered as "on topic" on StackOverflow. Such questions can still be useful to developers, and these rules can be disadvantageous to the usefulness of StackOverflow. To follow the rules, you could attempt to implement a Spliterator yourself and add your code showing where you're stuck and ask for specific advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An ideal trySplit method efficiently (without traversal) divides its
>   elements exactly in half, allowing balanced parallel computation. Many
>   departures from this ideal remain highly effective; for example, only
>   approximately splitting an approximately balanced tree, or for a tree
>   in which leaf nodes may contain either one or two elements, failing to
>   further split these nodes. However, large deviations in balance and/or
>   overly inefficient trySplit mechanics typically result in poor
>   parallel performance.

and the method structure with comments

```
 public Spliterator<T> trySplit() {
   int lo = origin; // divide range in half
   int mid = ((lo + fence) >>> 1) & ~1; // force midpoint to be even
   if (lo < mid) { // split out left half
     origin = mid; // reset this Spliterator's origin
     return new TaggedArraySpliterator<>(array, lo, mid);
   }
   else       // too small to split
     return null;
 }
```

for more exposure read up on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html

Answer (score -1):

Here is the example of Implementing a Spliterator.

```
public class Payment {
    private String category;
    private double amount;

    public Payment(double amount, String category) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
}
```

TrySplit implementation :

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class PaymentBatchSpliterator implements Spliterator<Payment> {

    private List<Payment> paymentList;
    private int current;
    private int last;  // inclusive

    public PaymentBatchSpliterator(List<Payment> payments) {
        this.paymentList = payments;
        last = paymentList.size() - 1;
    }

    public PaymentBatchSpliterator(List<Payment> payments, int start, int last) {
        this.paymentList = payments;
        this.current = start;
        this.last = last;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super Payment> action) {
        if (current <= last) {
            action.accept(paymentList.get(current));
            current++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Spliterator<Payment> trySplit() {
        if ((last - current) < 100) {
            return null;
        }

        // first stab at finding a split position
        int splitPosition = current + (last - current) / 2;
        // if the categories are the same, we can't split here, as we are in the middle of a batch
        String categoryBeforeSplit = paymentList.get(splitPosition-1).getCategory();
        String categoryAfterSplit = paymentList.get(splitPosition).getCategory();

        // keep moving forward until we reach a split between categories
        while (categoryBeforeSplit.equals(categoryAfterSplit)) {
            splitPosition++;
            categoryBeforeSplit = categoryAfterSplit;
            categoryAfterSplit = paymentList.get(splitPosition).getCategory();
        }

        // safe to create a new spliterator
        PaymentBatchSpliterator secondHalf = new PaymentBatchSpliterator(paymentList,splitPosition,last);
        // reset our own last value
        last = splitPosition - 1;

        return secondHalf;
    }

    @Override
    public long estimateSize() {
        return last - current;
    }

    @Override
    public int characteristics() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Is is a example from GitHub [Reference](https://github.com/hedleyproctor/java8-examples/tree/master/src/main/java/com/example/java8/spliterator)