# Doesn't Stream.parallel() update the characteristics of spliterator?

Tags: java, java-stream

This question is based on the answers to this question [What is the difference between Stream.of and IntStream.range?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67669583/7804477)

Since the `IntStream.range` produces an already sorted stream, the output to the below code would only generate the output as `0`:

```java
IntStream.range(0, 4)
         .peek(System.out::println)
         .sorted()
         .findFirst();
```

Also the spliterator would have `SORTED` characteristics. Below code returns `true`:

```java
System.out.println(
    IntStream.range(0, 4)
             .spliterator()
             .hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SORTED)
);
```

Now, If I introduce a `parallel()` in the first code, then as expected, the output would contain all 4 numbers from `0` to `3` but in a random order, because the stream is not sorted anymore due to `parallel()`.

```java
IntStream.range(0, 4)
         .parallel()
         .peek(System.out::println)
         .sorted()
         .findFirst();
```

This would produce something like below: (in any random order)

```
2
0
1
3
```

So, I expect that the `SORTED` property has been removed due to `parallel()`. But, the below code returns `true` as well.

```java
System.out.println(
    IntStream.range(0, 4)
             .parallel()
             .spliterator()
             .hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SORTED)
);
```

Why doesn't the `parallel()` change `SORTED` property? And since all four numbers are printed, **How does Java realize that the stream is not sorted even though the `SORTED` property still exists?**

Comment: It's not the Characteristics, they are the same for both your code blocks. You can verify that using `spliterator.characteristics()`. But yeah, the interest remains in the primary question to get an answer which completes the explanation to just _What_ but _Why_ and _How_. Both the existing answers don't really suffice in my opinion.

Comment: @Naman  let me know what you think of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67690928/1059372)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How exactly this is done is very much an implementation detail. You will have to dig deep inside the source code to really see why. Basically, parallel and sequential pipelines are just handled differently. Look at the [`AbstractPipeline.evaluate`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/AbstractPipeline.java#l226), which checks `isParallel()`, then does different things depending whether the pipeline is parallel.

```
    return isParallel()
           ? terminalOp.evaluateParallel(this, sourceSpliterator(terminalOp.getOpFlags()))
           : terminalOp.evaluateSequential(this, sourceSpliterator(terminalOp.getOpFlags()));
```

If you then look at [`SortedOps.OfInt`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/SortedOps.java#l166), you'll see that it overrides two methods:

```
@Override
public Sink<Integer> opWrapSink(int flags, Sink sink) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(sink);

    if (StreamOpFlag.SORTED.isKnown(flags))
        return sink;
    else if (StreamOpFlag.SIZED.isKnown(flags))
        return new SizedIntSortingSink(sink);
    else
        return new IntSortingSink(sink);
}

@Override
public <P_IN> Node<Integer> opEvaluateParallel(PipelineHelper<Integer> helper,
                                               Spliterator<P_IN> spliterator,
                                               IntFunction<Integer[]> generator) {
    if (StreamOpFlag.SORTED.isKnown(helper.getStreamAndOpFlags())) {
        return helper.evaluate(spliterator, false, generator);
    }
    else {
        Node.OfInt n = (Node.OfInt) helper.evaluate(spliterator, true, generator);

        int[] content = n.asPrimitiveArray();
        Arrays.parallelSort(content);

        return Nodes.node(content);
    }
}
```

`opWrapSink` will be eventually called if it's a sequential pipeline, and `opEvaluateParallel` (as its name suggests) will be called when it's a parallel stream. Notice how `opWrapSink` doesn't do anything to the given sink if the pipeline is already sorted (just returns it unchanged), but `opEvaluateParallel` always evaluates the spliterator.

Also note that parallel-ness and sorted-ness are not mutually exclusive. You can have a stream with any combination of those characteristics.

"Sorted" is a characteristic of a `Spliterator`. It's not technically a characteristic of a `Stream` (like "parallel" is). Sure, `parallel` could create a stream with an entirely new spliterator (that gets elements from the original spliterator) with entirely new characteristics, but why do that, when you can just reuse the same spliterator? Id imagine you'll have to handle parallel and sequential streams differently in any case.

Comment: I am just debugging through the rest of the answer :-), but I would like to get clarification on the last part of the answer. If we chain parallel and sequential operations, doesn't the mode of operation correspond to the last one? i.e if sequential was specified last, then the stream would be sequential even if the stream was initially parallel or even if we used `parallel()` in between?

Comment: @GauthamM Sorry, I brain farted. Please ignore that. I meant to say something about "sorted" implies "ordered", which shouldn't be removed by calling `parallel`, but then realised you are not asking about "ordered", and tried to make a similar point about "sorted", but ended up writing something that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @GauthamM I tried to explain in another way why the "sorted" isn't reset. See the edit.

Comment: so this is want i understood. First, it is actually the stream operation flag that makes the difference and not the spliterator characteristics.
Second, if sequential pipeline also always evaluate even if `SORTED` flag was present, then the output would have been `0123` (in order) instead of `0`. Is this correct?

Comment: @GauthamM Indeed, it is the stream op flag that matters, but your code is checking the spliterator flag, isn't it? In any case, the point that "deleting the characteristic just because you made it parallel is unnecessary" still stands, because parallel and sequential streams are handled differently regardless. As for your second point, I never said anything about "sequential pipeline also always evaluate even if `SORTED` flag was present". That's not true at all. As you can see in `opWrapSink`, if the stream is sorted, it does nothing to the sink, unlike the other cases.

Comment: I too did not say "sequential always evaluates even for SORTED..", I meant to ask -> "IF" it had always evaluated (instead of the current implementation), then would the output be `0123`?

Comment: @GauthamM Oh I see what you mean now :) Yes it would. That's what using `IntStream.of(1,2,3,4)` (no sorted characteristic) would do.

Comment: @GauthamM you need to have a much broader picture to understand why things work the way they are. I've tried to explain that.

Answer (score 4):

You need to take a step back and think of how you would solve such a problem *in general*, considering that `ForkJoinPool` is used for parallel streams and it works based on [work stealing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52717900/forkjoinpool-scheduling-vs-executorservice/52729788#52729788). It would be very helpful if you knew how a `Spliterator` works, too. Some details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51453841/difference-between-iterator-and-spliterator-in-java8/51459530#51459530).

You have a certain Stream, you "split it" (very simplified) into smaller pieces and give all those pieces to a `ForkJoinPool` for execution. All of those pieces are worked on independently, by individual threads. Since we are talking about *threads* here, there is obviously no sequence of events, things happen randomly (that is why you see a random order output).

If your stream preserves the *order*, terminal operation is suppose to preserve it too. So while *intermediate* operations are executed in *any* order, your terminal operation (if the stream up to that point is ordered), will handle elements in an ordered fashion. To put it slightly simplified:

```
System.out.println(
    IntStream.of(1,2,3)
             .parallel()
             .map(x -> {System.out.println(x * 2); return x * 2;})
             .boxed()
             .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

`map` will process elements in an unknown order (`ForkJoinPool` and threads, remember that), but `collect` will receive elements *in order*, "left to right".

---

Now, if we extrapolate that to your example: when you invoke `parallel`, the stream is split in small pieces and worked on. For example look how this is split (a single time).

```
Spliterator<Integer> spliterator =
IntStream.of(5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8)
         .parallel()
         .boxed()
         .sorted()
         .spliterator()
         .trySplit(); // trySplit is invoked internally on parallel

spliterator.forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
```

On my machine it prints `1,2,3,4`. This means that the internal implementation splits the stream in two `Spliterator`s: `left` and `right`. `left` has `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and right has `[5, 6, 7, 8]`. But that is not it, these `Spliterator`s can be split further. For example:

```
Spliterator<Integer> spliterator =
IntStream.of(5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8)
         .parallel()
         .boxed()
         .sorted()
         .spliterator()
         .trySplit()
         .trySplit()
         .trySplit();

spliterator.forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
```

if you try to invoke `trySplit` again, you will get a `null` - meaning, that's it, I can't split anymore.

So, your Stream : `IntStream.range(0, 4)` is going to be split in 4 spliterators. All worked on individually, by a thread. If your first thread knows that this `Spliterator` it currently works on, is the "left-most one", that's it! The rest of the threads do not even need to start their work - the result is known.

On the other hand, it could be that this `Spliterator` that has the "left-most" element is only started last. So the first three ones, might already be done with their work (thus `peek` is invoked in your example), but they do not "produce" the needed result.

As a matter fact, this is how it is [done internally](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/stream/FindOps.java#L310). You do not need to understand the code - but the flow and the method names should be obvious.

Comment: thanks. thought of dedicating a separate time to read through this. So here is what I understood (assuming 4 threads) -> `range(0,9).parallel().peek(print).sorted().findFirst()` Here, since we have `sorted()` along with `parallel()`, the `findFirst` waits for the completion of all 4 threads. Hence the output would always be 0 to 8 in a random order even if thread with 0 is processed first. (Continuing the rest in my next comment)

Comment: ...(contd)
Next i am changing the code by adding a similar `peek` after `sorted`.

`range(0,9).parallel().peek(print).sorted().peek(print).findFirst()`. Here as part of the second peek, even if thread with 0 is processed first, the rest of the 3 threads continue their operation (assume it has 4,7,1 respectively) and hence `4,7,1` is also printed. But no new elements would be picked for processing by any of the threads. So a minimum of 4 (number of threads) numbers would always be printed. Why is it that, as soon as result is found, the other threads are not interrupted/canceled immediately?

Comment: Also, inside `doLeaf` why are we not checking if the node is already cancelled. If it is already cancelled, is there a need to invoke `sinkSupplier.get()`? Couldn't we directly proceed to `cancelLaterNodes` ?